# can't run wildfly 9.0.2 from netbeans 8.1 under Windows 8.1

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, wildfly

I can't start my Wildfly server in Netbeans.
I am running Windows 8.1, WildFly 9.0.2 Final, Netbeans 8.1.

I get the error:

WildFly Application Server start failed. Check whether the standalone.bat script is executable.

The server does not start.

Note: I can start WildFly from a command shell using standalone.bat script and I can deploy my application from the admin console using a web browser.

My windows 8 account has administration rights and I have also tried running the server in Netbeans when I am logged in as Administrator. The error message is always the same.

I would be very grateful for any help you can give!